# Python function error string index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am to find out what is wrong with this code and apparently I do not see anything wrong because I've just gotten into learning python.

Also when I run the function it will give me an error of `"String Index out of range"`.

And I am to test if this does work.

**So what seems to be wrong and how should I be testing them?**

```
def is_reverse_of( st1, st2 ):

    """
    is_reverse_of : String String -> Boolean
    is_reverse_of tells if one string is the reverse of another.
    preconditions: st1 and st2 are character strings.
    """
    if len( st1 ) != len( st2 ):
        return False
    i = 0
    j = len( st2 )
    while j > 0:
        if st1[i] != st2[j]:
            return False
        else:
            i += 1
            j -= 1

    return True
```

This is what I got so far for the testing

```
def test_is_reverse_of():

    """
    a suite of pass/fail test cases to validate that is_reverse_of works.
    """
    # Complete this test function.
    st1 = str(input("Enter the string: "))
    st2 = str(input("Enter the string: "))

    is_reverse_of(st1, st2)
```

Comment: check your `[j]` indexing policy. Attempt to access j-th element of a string, which has length `len( aString ) == j` fails, as the indexing is zero-based --- `aString[0]`...`aString[len-1]`

Comment: `input` is already a  string so no need to cast   and `if st1[i] != st2[j-1]:` will solve your index error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index is 0-based, so it is from 0 to len(str2) - 1, not len(str2). You can easily fix the problem simply by doing:

```
j = len( st2 ) - 1
```

By the way, you really just need one index, eitehr i or j, since the other one can be easily calculated:

```
def is_reverse_of( st1, st2 ):
    if len( st1 ) != len( st2 ):
        return False
    l = len(st1)    
    for i in range(0, l):
        if st1[i] != st2[l - 1 - i]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I've fixed it up and ran the function and it works without an error. But now how should I start to test the function if it works or not (as in if it does indicate the strings are reverse to each other or not)

Comment: Try different cases and observe the results, for example: print(is_reverse_of( "ab","ba")) should print True; print(is_reverse_of( "ab","bac")) should print False etc.